# Asynchronous callback return value

Tags: javascript, web3js

```
web3.eth.getCoinbase(function(err, account) {
      if (err === null) {
        return account;
      }  
    });
```

How do you return a callback for an asynchronous function such as the one in the code above?  How do I access the the value account outside of that function?  My goal is to access the value "account".  The synchronous version of this function would be something simple such as

```
App.account = web3.eth.coinbase;
```